# Temp Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript

I've run into this issue before, and have hacked away at it to get the results I need, but am finally against the wall and am not understanding why this keeps occuring.

In JavaScript, *how can I capture only a shallow copy that doesn't point back to the original object?* This is driving me crazy. I get that everything's a pointer in JS, but there's got to be a way to get a deep copy that, when modified, doesn't change the original object. Here's the code I am working with:

```
MyGame.runAllPossibleMoves = function() {
MyGame.ai_object.board = MyGame.tetrominos;
MyGame.ai_object.piece = MyGame.tetromino;

  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(i < MyGame.ai_object.piece.pivot.x){
      while(moveLeft() && i < MyGame.ai_object.piece.pivot.x){
       //do piece movement
      }

      hardDrop();
    }
    console.log(MyGame.ai_object.piece.pivot.x + ',' + MyGame.ai_object.piece.pivot.y);
    console.log(MyGame.tetromino.pivot.x + ',' + MyGame.tetromino.pivot.y);
    MyGame.ai_object.board = MyGame.tetrominos;
    MyGame.ai_object.piece = MyGame.tetromino;
    //console.log(MyGame.ai_object.piece);
  }
}
```

The object, `MyGame.tetromino`, is being updated to whatever `MyGame.ai_object.piece` is when what I really want to do is modify the *temp* variable I've created and use `MyGame.tetromino` to reset my temp object. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At it's simplest, and assuming that nothing has unsafely extended `Object.prototype`:

```
Object.shallowCopy = function(obj) {
    var r = Array.isArray(obj) ? new Array(obj.length) : {};
    for (var k in obj) {
        r[k] = obj[k];
    }
    return r;
}
```

As this is a shallow copy, any value "copied" that is itself an object will remain a reference to the original value.

Equivalent functions exist in various libraries.  In particular (and without the DOM baggage associated with jQuery) there's [`_.clone`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) in underscore.js

**EDIT** - for a deep copy, simple recursion should suffice, again assuming that neither `Object.prototype` nor `Array.prototype` have been unsafely modified:

```
Object.deepCopy = function(obj) {
    var r = obj;
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        r = Array.isArray(obj) ? new Array(obj.length) : {};
        for (var k in obj) {
            r[k] = Object.deepCopy(obj[k]);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

NB: this function will fail to complete if passed a structure that contains a circular reference to itself.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, I would call this function and it would return to me the shallow copy of an object.

Comment: @sparkyShorts exactly, yes.  `var copy = Object.shallowCopy(original)`

Comment: So I implemented it, like you suggested, but I am still not getting a shallow copy. I see and understand how your code is working, but I don't understand how it's creating a shallow copy. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @sparkyShorts: This code gives you a **shallow** copy - that is, it de-references by 1 layer. Do you want a **deep** copy instead?

Comment: @slebetman  Well that is embarrassing, I was thinking of deep copy and saying shallow copy the whole time. *facepalm*. No wonder. My only excuse is that it's 1 am. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing that I had asked for a shallow copy but was indeed needing a *deep* copy (had them backwards for some reason, not enough caffeine I guess), I found this on the interwebs and in several other answers:

```
MyGame.ai_object.board = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyGame.tetrominos)));
MyGame.ai_object.piece = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyGame.tetromino)));
```

This created the deep copy that I was looking for. There are several other answers on SO that I found after realizing my mistake.

EDIT:

Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) uses up a ton of resources. Here is an alternative way to get a deep copy:

```
deepCopy = function(obj){
  var temp;
  for(var n in obj){
    temp[n] = obj[n];
  }
  return temp;
}
```

This copies each item in obj and assigns it to the new object, temp. This will not create a deep copy of any objects within obj (you'd have to call deepCopy again).